# Can I define "shell out" as "to pay an excessive amount of money unwillingly or angrily"?

Tags: definition

I found some definitions of "shell out" as follows:

- To spend a certain amount of money (http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shell+out)
- To pay for something, generally applies to paying large amounts of money (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shell%20out)
- Having to pay an amount of money for something, especially if unexpected or having to pay more than one thinks is a fair price (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shell%20out)
- (informal) Pay (a specified amount of money, especially one regarded as excessive)(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shell)

Can I define *shell out* as "to pay an excessive amount of money unwillingly or angrily"?

Comment: I think your problem here is misunderstanding of the word **unwillingly**. In English, it means *forced*, or *against your will*; a direct language calque of the word to some other languages carries the meaning of *reluctantly*. Yes, you *shell out* money *reluctantly*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the adverb *reluctantly*, not *unwillingly*. In other words, you had to pay a little more than you had hoped to pay, but *shelled out* doesn't always imply getting ripped off:

> **Ted**: How much did you pay for those tickets?
>   **Ed**: I had to shell out more than $100 each.
>   **Ted**: Wow, that's expensive.

If I overheard this conversation, I'd assume Ed was hoping to pay somewhere between $50 and $80 each, but he had to go a little higher than he wanted. He's still glad he got the tickets, though.

The phrase *shelled out* doesn't imply highway robbery – but perhaps it does suggest digging a little deeper into the wallet than one had initially hoped. I might use *shelled out* after a momentary twinge of "sticker shock."

Answer (score 1):

No, *shell out* doesn't imply any angriness or unwillingness. If you need to convoy that meaning, you need to make it explicit in the rest of the sentence. I could pay something more than I want to pay it, but I could really need it, and I am willing to pay it even if I pay it  more than I would have expected.

Comment: Ok，I see, thank you. But why is there "especially if unexpected or having to pay more than one thinks is a fair price" in the dictionary definition?

Comment: +1. Although I see "usually unwillingly" in the definition in [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/shell-sth-out), I agree with this answer. It's too easy to find examples where there's no "unwillingness": "Kat was **willing to shell out** for new clothes." (COCA) "**Having agreed to shell out**, Barclaycard chief executive Bob Potts asked a favour of Scudamore." (Collins) "**Do you think we should shell out** for the extra options package?" (Wiktionary) "Consumers are **willing to shell out** money to own a brand" (vocabulary.com)  And so on.

Comment: @dennylv: That definition only says *especially* - there's nothing to say you *can't* use the expression in respect routine or cheap/fairly-priced expenditure. Also note that the *first* attribute mentionned is ***unexpected***. It's quite normal to say things like [*I couldn't pass up the **opportunity to get it for cheap, so I shelled out a few bucks** and got a couple more games*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22for+cheap%2C+so+I+shelled+out+a+few+bucks%22&oq=%22for+cheap%2C+so+I+shelled+out+a+few+bucks%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5349j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).